# Change enumeration style in exercises using xsim

Tags: lists, exercises, xsim

Forgive me if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find this question, exactly.  I'm using the `xsim` package (documentclass `book`) and I'd like my "top"-level enumeration to be labeled with letters in my exercises, but with Arabic numerals outside of those.  So, for instance, if I type

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Hello
\end{enumerate}
```

outside of the exercises, I want it to read

> 1. Hello

but if I type it within an exercise environment I want it to read

> a. Hello

Obviously I could hack this by changing my enumeration labeling style each time I enumerate within an exercise, but there has to be a better way.  Right? Keep in mind I'm using the default `exercise` environment supplied by `xsim`.

Comment: please post MWE of the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either add the re-definition with the `pre-hook` or `begin-hook` options to the exercise environments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/begin-hook = \renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}} ,
  solution/begin-hook = \renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item bla bla
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

Outside:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

or just add the redefinition inside the code of a custom environment template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}
  {%
    \UseExerciseTemplate{begin}{default}%
    \renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}%
  }
  {\UseExerciseTemplate{end}{default}}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template=custom ,
  solution/template=custom
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item bla bla
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

Outside:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!